# How to use TopK operator in vectorized_map in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I was trying to perform a **tf.vectorized_map** on a tensor of shape **[batchsize, listsize]** and apply the **tf.math.top_k** operator over every row in the batch and did not succed.

For example the data could be :

```
[ [1,2,4,5,6], [9,5,4,2,1] ]
```

and I would like to apply topk on `[1,2,4,5,6]` and on `[9,5,4,2,1]`.

However I succeded as doing the same thing with `tf.map_fn` but `vectorized_map` should run faster. I use **tensorflow 1.15**.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# create fake data
x = tf.convert_to_tensor([
    [1,2,4,5,6],
    [9,5,4,2,1],
], dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.reshape(x, (2, -1))

B = x.shape[0] # batchsize
L = x.shape[1] # list size

print(f"B {B}, L {L}")

sess = tf.Session()

print(f"x tensor: {sess.run(x)}\n")

def fv(_x):
    #_tensor = tf.reshape(_x, (L,))  # doesnt work (1)
    _tensor = tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor([9,5,4,2,1], dtype=tf.float32), (L,)) # work (2)
    #_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor([9,5,4,2,1], dtype=tf.float32) # work (3)

    print(f"_tensor: {_tensor}")
    values, indices = tf.math.top_k(_tensor, k=3)
    # i just need the indices
    return indices

indices = tf.vectorized_map(
        fv,
        x,
)
print("\nindices ")
print(sess.run(indices))
```

As we can see (2) and (3) run, so the topk operator should be usable. Also even if (1) does not work, I can use the _x and for example just return it like :

```py
def fv(_x):
    return _x * 10
```

So the _x is usable.

So when I run the code with (1) I have the error :

```
ValueError: No converter defined for TopKV2
name: "loop_body/TopKV2"
op: "TopKV2"
input: "loop_body/Reshape"
input: "loop_body/TopKV2/k"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "sorted"
  value {
    b: true
  }
}

inputs: [WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/Reshape/pfor/Reshape:0' shape=(2, 5) dtype=float32>, is_stacked=True, is_sparse_stacked=False), WrappedTensor(t=<tf.Tensor 'loop_body/TopKV2/k:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, is_stacked=False, is_sparse_stacked=False)]. 
Either add a converter or set --op_conversion_fallback_to_while_loop=True, which may run slower

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here I just try to get the indices, after I will need to process the vector to have like `[[0,0,1,1,1], [1,1,1,0,0] ]` in output for `K=3` (1 if the values is in the topk else 0). And also to give another tensor of shape [batchsize, 1] containing the K paremeter for every row. (I already succeded doing this with map_fn so I dont think it will be a problem later).

Maybe it is possible to implement my own topk operator in the vectorized map but I would rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did something like that :
This do not use the vectorized_map, but it is what I wanted to do. But if someone can make it works with vectorized_map I would look at the solution. :)

```py
def topk(x, k):
    """
    x : shape [B, L]
    k : shape [B, 1]
    return : final_mask of shape [B,L] with final_mask[b,i] = 0 if x[b,i] is in  
    the k[b] biggest values of x[b,:], else final_mask[b,i] = 1
    """
    B = x.shape[0]  # batchsize
    L = x.shape[1]  # list size

    # the indices sorted in descending order
    indices_des = tf.argsort(x, axis=-1, direction='DESCENDING', stable=False, name='sorting_for_topk')

    
    mask = tf.reshape(tf.range(start=0, limit=L, dtype=tf.int32), [1, L])
    mask = tf.repeat(mask, [B], axis=0)
    mask = mask<k

    one_hot = tf.one_hot(indices_des, depth=L) * tf.cast(tf.reshape(mask, [B, L, 1]), tf.float32)
    final_mask = tf.reduce_sum(one_hot, axis=1)
    
    return final_mask
```